# cakephp sort link not working

Tags: cakephp, sorting, hyperlink

Can't make sort links work. (concrete or virtual fields).

Vitual fields for my sum() field on this action:

```
    $this->Qca->virtualFields['comps'] = 'Sum(CASE WHEN Qca.qca_tipcode = 1 THEN 1 END)';
    $this->Qca->virtualFields['production'] = 'Sum(qca_end - qca_start)';
    $this->Qca->virtualFields['idle'] = 'Sum(Qca.qca_durend)';
```

My find(), works fine:

```
    $hoursvalues = $this->Qca->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions,
        'fields' => array('Qca.dir_id', 'Qca.name', 'Sum(CASE WHEN Qca.qca_tipcode = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Qca__comps', 'Sum(qca_end - qca_start) as Qca__production', 'Sum(Qca.qca_durend) as Qca__idle'),
        'group' => array('Qca.dir_id')
            )
    );
```

and then:

```
   $this->paginate('Qca' );
   $this->set('hoursvalues', $hoursvalues);
```

What extra settings does `$this->paginate('Qca' );` needs? Please note I have all data I need via find().

What is it I'm missing that sorting does not work for either concrete or virtual fields?

Thansk a lot!

Carlos

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is the following:

```
$this->paginate('Qca');
$this->set('hoursvalues', $hoursvalues);
```

`$this->paginate()` returns an array with sorted values. What you need to do is specify your extra settings in `$this->paginate` array and then

```
$this->set('hoursvalues', $this->paginate('Qca'));
```

For your other fields, making them `virtualFields` will make them easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you Tigrand; If I use `$this->set('hoursvalues', $this->paginate('Qca'));` the array does not travel to my view, I need to use $hoursvalues, Can you please elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: Hi. I upgrade the questions thank to your virtualfields note (my array is now simpler), still, can't make sort links work. Will you please take a look?  Thank you !